# How to select subset of users based on many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

`User` and `Organization` have a many-to-many association through `Relationship`.

One of the variables in the `Relationship` model is a boolean called `member`.
A `user` can occur in the `Relationship` model multiple times as a `user` can be related to multiple `organizations`.

How can I select a random instance from all the `users` that 1) don't have a relationship with any `organization` (so don't occur in the `Relationship` model) plus 2) those `users` that do have a relationship with an organization but for whom `member = false` for *all* their relationships with organizations?

I was thinking of something like:

```
user = User.where( relationship_id = nil || ??? ).offset(rand(0..100)).first
```

Comment: Please put the code of the relationships so we can better understand your particular case.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code to the original post.

Comment: If a user had a single Relationship with an organisation, and that had member = true, are then in or out of this selection?

Comment: @Max, then they are out of the selection (either have no relationship at all, or for all relationships have `member = false`).

Comment: This smells like the sort of instance where if you explained what you actually want to do, in english not code, then it might become apparent that you don't even need to do the thing you're asking about.  What do you actually want to get, in a common sense sort of explanation?

Comment: When seeding, I want to give certain rights to a random selection of users who are not a member of any organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do this

1. `User.joins("LEFT JOIN relationships ON relationships.user_id = users.id").where('relationships.user_id IS NULL').offset(rand(0..100)).first`
2. Something like:

   ```
   member_ids = Relationship.where(member: true).pluck(:user_id).uniq
   users = User.where.not(id: member_ids) # or User.where('id NOT in (?)', member_ids) on Rails < 4
   ```

---

Comment: The first one ignores the not a member of any context e.g. (member = false on all relationships) and also could be simplified with `includes(:relationships)` rather than the raw SQL join. The second answer is how I would handle this .

Comment: You actually can't use `includes`, because then condition on included relationship won't work: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes (see 'conditions' section). You could add some boilerplate ('reference' call) to make it work, but I consider that using 'joins' in the first place is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you actually want is users who aren't a member of any organisations, where "being a member" means "having a relationship join record where member = true".  This is a much simpler concept than the conditions you specified.

In that case:

- get distinct user_id from relationships where member = true
- get users whose id IS NOT in this list

eg

```
member_ids = Relationship.where(member: true).distinct.pluck(:user_id)
@users = User.where("id not in (?)", member_ids).all
```

Comment: Thanks Max, this seems as it should do what I'm looking. I fail to test it because seeding fails. If you might also have an idea why that is, I'd love to hear.

Comment: I would do a different question for that, since it's a seperate problem.  Generally, though, if you give people zero information other than "it fails" they won't be able to diagnose your problem ;-)

Comment: Okay, will do (once I can post another question). Once I get the seeding to work will report back if the code works. I'll roll back this post to remove the seeding issue.

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution will require database to send IDs of every Relationship record to your ruby code. And then your ruby code will have to send it back again. It's probably a better idea to make database filter ids by itself ;)

Comment: Don't use SQL code inside where function, because it is susceptible of SQL Injection. Instead use `@users = User.where.not(id: member_ids).all`. Look at @Andrea Salicetti answer, it's what you want.

Comment: In `User.where("id not in (?)", member_ids)`, rails will sanitize member_ids.  Also, because i'm building this myself, rather than just shoving some value from `param` in there, sql injection isn't even an issue.

Comment: Similar to @AndreaSalicetti's only it is completely backwards compatible. Distinction is not needed as SQL will handle this fine e.g. `SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE id NOT IN(1,1,1);` will still only return 1 result. Although I don't feel it would have any overall performance impact either way.

Comment: Hey @MaxWilliams! Is there any progress with the issue? :)

Comment: @EugZol i don't know which issue you are referring to.  This question has an answer marked as correct and is therefore concluded as far as i'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

For getting Users with no Organization:

```
User.where.not(id: Relationship.pluck(:user_id).uniq)
```

The other query doesn't seem like something you could be doing without some logic to compare the total Relationships for a User against those where member = false.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem which you can use. (Full disclosure: I've created that gem recently.)

```
# This will select all users, for which there are not relationships,
# or there is a relationship, but its 'member' attributes is false.
#
# Just what you've asked for.
users_to_select = User.where_not_exists(:relationships, member: true)

# 'offset' and 'count' will work as usual after 'where_not_exists'
random_user = users_to_select.offset(rand(users_to_select.count)).first
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, using ActiveRecord doesn't presume that you are prohibited to write SQL code. Actually, you are *required* to do so in many cases. Your case seems to be one of these (you can't do 'OR' query with ActiveRecord, and you there is no syntax sugar for SQL 'WHERE EXISTS').

So I suggest you do something like:

```
free_users = User.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relationships WHERE user_id = users.id) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM relationships WHERE user_id = users.id AND member = FALSE)")
random_user = User.find(free_users.ids.sample)
```

More info on SQL "EXISTS":

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

**UPD**. Posted another answer which utilizes `where_exists` gem.

Comment: User doesn't have relationship_id

Comment: @MiguelCunha And why exactly shouldn't I?

Comment: But I don't have SQL injection in provided example, and neither should you have it in your SQL in where's. If you need to shove some parameters into raw SQL, use placeholders: http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/01/named-placeholders-in-active-record-queries/ (first link from Google). Rails will auto-escape them. Using SQL fragments in Rails is mainstream practice, you shouldn't fear it. Actually, you are very limited being stuck with only simplest methods that Ruby interface gives you.

Comment: @MiguelCunha where could this method possibly be injected? There is no user input required. Also when using the `?` placeholder as in some of the other answers rails sanitizes the values appropriately as if they were passed in as a Hash.

Comment: Look at @Andrea Salicetti answer. Also [this website is very interesting about injection in rails](http://rails-sqli.org/). You should use Rails functions wherever possible. I know that there are some limitations, but you can use additional libraries for that or you can (and should) rethink the app conceptual model / architecture.

Comment: @MiguelCunha His answer gives more concise code, I give him that. But it will transfer ids of every relationship record twice: first to rails and then back again to DB engine. In most cases such thing should be avoided. Your link is irrelevant, because it presents cases where placeholders (named or unnamed `?`) ARE NOT used.