# Rails: How to Select Records Which Don't Have a Specific Related (associated) Object (SQL EXISTS brief how-to)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, exists

Let's assume we have users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :groups, through: :connections
end
```

And groups:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections
  has_many :users, through: :connections
end
```

Basically, standard many-to-many connection:

```
class Connection
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

What I intend to do is:

- Select only users who don't belong to given set of Groups (groups with ids `[4,5,6]`)
- Select only users who belong to one set of Groups (`[1,2,3]`) and don't belong to another (`[4,5,6]`)
- Select only users who don't belong to a Group

Also, I don't want to:

- Fetch a lot of data from database to manipulate it with Ruby code. I know that will be inefficient in terms of CPU and memory (Ruby is much slower than any commonly used DB engine, and typically I want to rely on DB engine to do the heavy lifting)
- I tried queries like `User.joins(:group).where(group_id: [1,2,3]).where.not(group_id: [4,5,6])` and they return wrong results (some users from the result set belong to groups 4,5,6 *as well as* 1,2,3)
- I don't want to do `join` merely for the sake of only checking for existence, because I know that that is a pretty complex (i.e. CPU/memory-intensive) operation for DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such questions are pretty common amongst beginner to middle-level Rails developers. You know `ActiveRecord` interface and basic `SQL` operations, but you are stumbled on such kind of tasks as outlined in the question. (Couple of examples of such questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991653/make-a-request-with-activerecord-to-get-only-the-users-from-groups-and-not-from/31992086#31992086), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749281/how-to-select-subset-of-users-based-on-many-to-many-relationship/31749763#31749763)).

The answer is simple: use SQL [`EXISTS` condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php). Quick reference from the given URL:

> **Syntax**
>
> The syntax for the SQL EXISTS condition is:
>
> ```
> WHERE EXISTS ( subquery );
> ```
>
> **Parameters or Arguments**
>
> subquery
>
> The subquery is a `SELECT` statement. If the subquery returns at least one record in its result set, the `EXISTS` clause will evaluate to true and the `EXISTS` condition will be met. If the subquery does not return any records, the `EXISTS` clause will evaluate to false and the `EXISTS` condition will not be met.

It is also mentioned that `EXISTS` might be slower than `JOIN`, but that is usually not true. From the [Exists v. Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082449/exists-vs-join-and-use-of-exists-clause) question on SO:

> `EXISTS` is only used to test if a subquery returns results, and short circuits as soon as it does. `JOIN` is used to extend a result set by combining it with additional fields from another table to which there is a relation. [...] If you have proper indexes, most of the time the `EXISTS` will perform identically to the `JOIN`. The exception is on very complicated subqueries, where it is normally quicker to use `EXISTS`.

So, the database doesn't need to look through all the connections (it stops 'joining' records with 'exists' as soon as it founds the right one), and doesn't need to return all the fields from the table joined (just check that the corresponding row, well, does exist).

Answering the specific questions:

> Select only such users, who don't belong to given set of Groups (groups with ids `[4,5,6]`)

```
not_four_to_six = User.where("NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM connections
   WHERE connections.user_id = users.id
   AND connections.group_id IN (?)
  )", [4,5,6])
```

> Select only such users, who belong to one set of Groups (`[1,2,3]`) and don't belong to another (`[4,5,6]`)

```
one_two_three = not_four_to_six.where("EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM connections
   WHERE connections.user_id = users.id
   AND connections.group_id IN (?)
  )", [1,2,3])
```

> Select only such users, who doesn't belong to a Group

```
User.where("NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM connections
   WHERE connections.user_id = users.id
  )")
```