# Error when combining search scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, named-scope, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I have a web-service that allows clients to search for articles with query parameters.It works fine if only one parameter is included but fails if I combine `search_query` and  `category`. This is based on [Comfortable_Mexican_Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki) where [for_category](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/5162ec28a97ad8ada20cde89653aac5f35bc0d0d/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/extensions/is_categorized.rb) is found. Even if I remove the `order` statement i get this error.

#### error

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY
>   expressions must appear in select list LINE 1:
>   ...ms_categories"."label" = 'Company News'  ORDER BY pg_search_...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT DISTINCT "comfy_cms_pages".* FROM "comfy_cms_pages" INNER JOIN
>   "comfy_cms_categorizations" ON
>   "comfy_cms_categorizations"."categorized_id" = "comfy_cms_pages"."id"
>   AND "comfy_cms_categorizations"."categorized_type" = $1 INNER JOIN
>   "comfy_cms_categories" ON "comfy_cms_categories"."id" =
>   "comfy_cms_categorizations"."category_id" INNER JOIN (SELECT
>   "comfy_cms_pages"."id" AS pg_search_id,
>   (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple',
>   coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."content_cache"::text, '')) ||
>   to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."label"::text, ''))),
>   (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'austin' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS
>   rank FROM "comfy_cms_pages" WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple',
>   coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."content_cache"::text, '')) ||
>   to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."label"::text, '')))
>   @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'austin' || ' ''' || ':*')))))
>   pg_search_comfy_cms_pages ON "comfy_cms_pages"."id" =
>   pg_search_comfy_cms_pages.pg_search_id WHERE (layout_id = '1' AND
>   is_published = 't') AND "comfy_cms_categories"."label" = 'Company
>   News'  ORDER BY pg_search_comfy_cms_pages.rank DESC,
>   "comfy_cms_pages"."id" ASC, "comfy_cms_pages"."created_at" DESC

#### app/models/article.rb

```
class Article < Comfy::Cms::Page
  cms_is_categorized
  include PgSearch


  pg_search_scope :search_by_keywords, against: [:content_cache, :label], using: { tsearch: { any_word: true, prefix: true } }
```

#### app/commands/search_articles_command.rb

```
class SearchArticlesCommand
  def initialize(params = {})
    @since = params[:since_date]
    @keys = params[:search_query]
    @category = params[:category]
  end

  def execute
    Article.unscoped do
      query = if @since.present?
                Article.article.since_date(@since)
              else
                Article.published_article
              end
      query = query.for_category(@category) if @category.present?
      query = query.search_by_keywords(@keys) if @keys.present?
      query.where('').order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
end
```

#### comfortable-mexican-sofa/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/extensions/is_categorized.rb

```
module ComfortableMexicanSofa::IsCategorized

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cms_is_categorized
      include ComfortableMexicanSofa::IsCategorized::InstanceMethods

      has_many :categorizations,
        :as         => :categorized,
        :class_name => 'Comfy::Cms::Categorization',
        :dependent  => :destroy
      has_many :categories,
        :through    => :categorizations,
        :class_name => 'Comfy::Cms::Category'

      attr_accessor :category_ids

      after_save :sync_categories

      scope :for_category, lambda { |*categories|
        if (categories = [categories].flatten.compact).present?
          self.distinct.
            joins(:categorizations => :category).
            where('comfy_cms_categories.label' => categories)
        end
      }
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def sync_categories
      (self.category_ids || {}).each do |category_id, flag|
        case flag.to_i
        when 1
          if category = Comfy::Cms::Category.find_by_id(category_id)
            category.categorizations.create(:categorized => self)
          end
        when 0
          self.categorizations.where(:category_id => category_id).destroy_all
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ComfortableMexicanSofa::IsCategorized

### Updated Error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 4: ...e = 'Class' AND categorized_id = 'comfy_cms_pages'.'id' AND ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "comfy_cms_pages".* FROM "comfy_cms_pages" INNER JOIN (SELECT "comfy_cms_pages"."id" AS pg_search_id, (ts_rank((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."content_cache"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."label"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'austin' || ' ''' || ':*')), 0)) AS rank FROM "comfy_cms_pages" WHERE (((to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."content_cache"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('simple', coalesce("comfy_cms_pages"."label"::text, ''))) @@ (to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || 'austin' || ' ''' || ':*'))))) pg_search_comfy_cms_pages ON "comfy_cms_pages"."id" = pg_search_comfy_cms_pages.pg_search_id WHERE "comfy_cms_pages"."layout_id" = $1 AND "comfy_cms_pages"."is_published" = $2 AND (
        EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM categorizations
          WHERE categorized_type = 'Class' AND categorized_id = 'comfy_cms_pages'.'id' AND category_id IN (2)
        ))  ORDER BY pg_search_comfy_cms_pages.rank DESC, "comfy_cms_pages"."id" ASC
```

#### working solution but not a scope and have to be careful of order its being called

```
  def self.for_category(_category)
    Comfy::Cms::Categorization.includes(:category).references(:category).select(:categorized).pluck(:categorized_id)
    find(ids)
  end
```

Comment: Add source code of your `for_category` scope.

Comment: @EugZol I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by applying `reorder` to the result of the pg_search result.

#### search_command.rb

```
class SearchArticlesCommand
  def initialize(params = {})
    @since = params['since_date']
    @keys = params['search_query']
    @category = params['category']
  end

  def execute
    Article.unscoped do
      query = Article.article
      query = if @since.present?
                query.since_date(@since)
              else
                query.published
              end
      query = query.for_category(@category) if @category.present?
      query = query.search_by_keywords(@keys).reorder('updated_at DESC') if @keys.present?
      query
    end
  end
end
```

I also overrode for_category *(not required)*

#### article.rb

```
  scope :for_category, (lambda do |category|
    published
      .joins(:categories)
      .group(:id)
      .where('comfy_cms_categories.label' => category)
      .select('comfy_cms_pages.*')
  end)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to override `for_category` built-in filter of your CMS. Too many joins in that query.

Override `for_category` like this:

```
scope :for_category, lambda { |*categories|
  if (categories = [categories].flatten.compact).present?
    self_ids = "{connection.quote_table_name(self.table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(self.primary_key)}"
    self.where(
      "EXISTS (" +
        Comfy::Cms::Categorization.select('1').
          where(categorized_type: self.name).
          where('categorized_id' => self_ids).
          where(category_id: Comfy::Cms::Category.where(label: categories).pluck(:id)).to_sql +
      ")"
    )
  end
}
```

More on SQL `EXISTS` usage in Rails you can read in my [Rails: SQL EXISTS brief how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016346/rails-how-to-select-records-which-dont-have-a-specific-related-associated-ob/32016347#32016347).

More on why you bump into that error you can read in [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693089/pgerror-select-distinct-order-by-expressions-must-appear-in-select-list).

Specifically, `pg_search` wants order your results by rank. And `for_category` wants to select distinct fields of Article only, and doesn't care about search rank. Changing its code to use simple `EXISTS` instead of complex `JOIN` query will fix that.

Comment: It give the error undefined method `id' for #<Class:0x007fc711e960f8>

Comment: @AntarrByrd My bad. I've updated my answer, try again please.

Comment: It not throws a syntax error at `AND categorized_id = `

Comment: @AntarrByrd I don't quite understand you. Does it throw some new exception? Could you provide full text of it please?

Comment: After changing `categorizations` to `comfy_cms_categorizations` it doesn't throw an error but it return an empty list. And if I do it by category alone it returns everything

Comment: I posted a working solution I have above. Its not a scope however and I have to be careful to call it last when chaining

Comment: @AntarrByrd Your solution doesn't seem to filter anything: it just selects all categories.

Comment: @AntarrByrd I've updated my answer - rewritten for more clarity. The problem seems to be in `categorized_type` – please check whether it works if you set `Article` as in my answer edit.

Comment: Its actually Comfy::Cms::Page. After changing it from article it still returns everything

Comment: I don't quite get it. You said that it returned an empty list on previous iteration. Now it returns everything instead of only given categories? What does `Comfy::Cms::Categorization.distinct('categorized_type').map(&:categorized_type)` show?

Comment: It return everything if I only search by category? If I combine it with search_by_keywords it returns an empty list

Comment: Please clarify – if you use *only* search by category, does it return the right result set, or too much records (not only category you chose)?

Comment: It is returning every article I have instead just those with have the given category

Comment: You can try my gem [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists), which I've released recently. Your scope should work with one line: `self.where_exists(:categories, label: categories)`.

Comment: Sadly using the gem doesn't work either. When I search by the category alone nothing (empty relationship) is returned. `scope :for_category, ->(category) { where_exists(:categories, label: Array.wrap(category)) }` . The same if true when using a class method.

Comment: @AntarrByrd Definitely there's something wrong somewhere else. Ensure that you have `Categorization` and `Category` records in the database which point to your `Article`.